# write the query to get both Top 10 and Exclude & Include

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I have to use 3 fields ( answer , question;keyword , source)

1. My requirement is I need to Exclude the Field answer = "UNHANDLED"
2. I need the Field question.keyword
3. I need to INCLUDE the Field source = "sonax"

I Used the below query to get the output. But After applying the field answer = "UNHANDLED" I am still getting the Unhandled records in the data.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "term": {
          "answer": "UNHANDLED"
        }
      },
      "must": {
        "term": {
          "source": "sonax"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "top_tags": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "question.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_faq_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "answer"
              ]
            },
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Regards,
Prabhu

Comment: can you please share some sample index data and expected search result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "question": "c",
  "answer": "UNHANDLED",
  "source": "sonax"
}
{
  "question": "b",
  "answer": "c",
  "source": "titan"
}
{
  "question": "b",
  "answer": "q",
  "source": "sonax"
}
{
  "question": "d",
  "answer": "a",
  "source": "volvo"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "term": {
          "answer.keyword": "UNHANDLED"
        }
      },
      "must": {
        "term": {
          "source.keyword": "sonax"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "top_tags": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "question.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_faq_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "source"
              ]
            },
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "top_tags": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "b",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "top_faq_hits": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 0.6931471,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "65567523",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "3",
                  "_score": 0.6931471,
                  "_source": {
                    "source": "sonax"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Prabhudas8703 please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: @Prabhudas8703 glad I could help you 